# Find all text inputs on webpage with Haskell webdriver package

Tags: haskell, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Here is my attempt at finding all inputs of type "text" on a webpage. I have since figured out I could use xpath, but I'd like to know how to make the way I attempted work. I'm most interested in how I would lifft my [Element] into the [WD Element] and make this program valid.

However if my approach is just wrong or unidiomatic, feel free to totally rewrite it. Here is the code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import           Control.Monad
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class
import           Test.WebDriver
import           Test.WebDriver.Classes       (WebDriver (..))
import           Test.WebDriver.Commands
import           Test.WebDriver.Commands.Wait

main = do
  runSession defaultSession capabilities $ do
      openPage "http://www.appnitro.com/demo/view.php?id=1"
      inputs <- findElems $ ByTag "input"
      textElems <- filterM (liftM $ ((==) "text" . (`attr` "type"))) inputs
      -- wait 20 seconds
      waitUntil 20 (getText <=< findElem $ ByCSS ".doesnotexist")
        `onTimeout` return ""
  liftIO $ putStrLn "done"
    where
      capabilities = allCaps { browser=firefox }

-- [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( src/Main.hs, interpreted )

-- src/Main.hs:168:70:
--     Couldn't match type `Element' with `WD Element'
--     Expected type: [WD Element]
--       Actual type: [Element]
--     In the second argument of `filterM', namely `inputs'
--     In a stmt of a 'do' block:
--       textElems <- filterM
--                      (liftM $ ((==) "text" . (`attr` "type"))) inputs
--     In the second argument of `($)', namely
--       `do { openPage "http://www.appnitro.com/demo/view.php?id=1";
--             inputs <- findElems $ ByTag "input";
--             textElems <- filterM
--                            (liftM $ ((==) "text" . (`attr` "type"))) inputs;
--             waitUntil 20 (getText <=< findElem $ ByCSS ".doesnotexist")
--             `onTimeout` return "" }'
-- Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: Sorry I'm unfamiliar with the `Haskell` bindings but I think I can follow your code. I do wonder if you've tried using an xpath based find instead of your list of inputs and then filtering those? I'm making a guess here of the code but something like `textElems <- findElems $ ByXPath "//input[@type='text']"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your text elem filtering with this piece:

```
      textElems <- filterM textElem inputs
```

And then add this where:

```
      textElem e = (== Just "text") `fmap` (e `attr` "type")
```

But then you will still have the line with waitUntil that doesn't compile. That seems unrelated though as it has nothing to do with the filtering.

Answer (score 3):

This might not be the answer you were looking for, but I find it best to express these kinds of constraints on elements directly in the locators, in order not to clutter the haskell sources. As you mention using XPath is one possibility:

```
textElems <- findElems $ ByXPath "//input[@type='text']"
```

but I often prefer CSS selectors, which tend to be briefer (alas a bit less powerful - e.g. you cannot traverse from given element to its parent etc.) and work just as well in these simple cases

```
textElems <- findElems $ ByCSS "input[type='text']"
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two errors in your code:

`attr` returns a `Maybe` value, thus you must compare with `Just "text"`.

And given that `attr` already returns a value in the `WD` monad, you just have to lift just the first function (has you had it, you were lifting everything, including the `attr` function):

```
textElems <- filterM (liftM ((==) (Just "text")) . (`attr` "type")) inputs
```

Or alternatively, since `WD` is also a Functor (I actually find this easier to understand, you are applying a pure function inside the monad returned by `attr`):

```
textElems <- filterM (fmap ((==) (Just "text")) . (`attr` "type")) inputs
```

Comment: Since equality is symmetric, you can replace the comparison with simply `(== Just "text")`.